# How to capture screenshot of video every 5 milliseconds using python

Tags: python, opencv, video

I would like to know how to write a code for reading a 5-10 second video and capturing a screemshot every 5 milliseconds of the video.

Thanking you,

Comment: figure out the frame rate of the video, and then calculate how many frames to skip each time

Comment: Have a look here in the section "Playing Video from file": https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html.  Calling `cap.read()` in a loop will decode all video frames. Save sampled frames in any frequency you like.

Comment: please clarify "screenshot". are you trying to record your computer's screen (not a video file), or do you have a video file you want to edit?

Comment: Video capture every 5 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pyautogui
import time


i = 0
t = time.time()
while True:
    time.sleep(.005)
    myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    myScreenshot.save(f'image{i}.png')
    i+=1
    if time.time()-t>=10: # Instead of 10s write the time of your video in second.
        break
```

Comment: As far as I understood, the OP actually wanted to save frames from a video file. I believe the mention of screenshot was misleading. I might have misunderstood.

Comment: @wohlstad I think you are right, But as OP says _" capture screenshot of video every 5 milliseconds"_ Then this will work.

Comment: OP is being confusing in their use of words. before clarification, we can't know.